# How to create a custom loss function where intermediate training outputs(tensor y_pred) of an RNN, are fed to another predefined RNN?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I wish to create a custom loss function which doesn't directly use the intermediate outputs of the RNN(y_pred), but instead feeds in the y_pred as inputs to another RNN(say RNN2, which has already been defined and trained), and use these predicted values as the parameters of loss function.

I try to call my custom loss function from the model.compile function, and that produces an error. Is it because i can't feed in an object of tensor data type to RNN2? Am i wrong to assume that y_pred has the intermediate outputs of training? 
Also a simple print command of the y_pred using sess throws an error too!
i.e

```
sess=tf.Session()
print(sess.eval(y_pred))
```

so is the problem fundamental to y_pred?

Anyway, this is code:

```py
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        predicted=rnn2.predict(y_pred)
        return K.mean(K.abs( predicted-y_true), axis=-1)

input_tensor = Input(shape=(1,1))
hidden = LSTM(100, activation='softmax',return_sequences=False)(input_tensor)
out = Dense(1, activation='softmax')(hidden)
model = Model(input_tensor, out)
model.compile(loss=custom_loss, optimizer='adam')
```

error

```
You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_19' with dtype float and shape [?,1,1]
     [[{{node input_19}}]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This probably something to do when you call `model.compile`. Did you try pass it(RNN2) as a new layer like.

```
RNN2.trainable = False #  [1]
model = Sequential()
model.add(RNN1)
model.add(RNN2)

def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        # predicted=rnn2.predict(y_pred)
        return K.mean(K.abs( y_pred-y_true), axis=-1)
```

## Edit

> Can you elaborate on how i can use a Model(RNN2) as a Layer in RNN1?

If it's me I'll to something like this.

```
from keras import models, layers


inp = layers.Input((None, 1))
x = layers.LSTM(512, return_sequences=True)(inp)
x = layers.LSTM(256)(x)
x = layers.Dense(32, name='rnn2_output')(x)
rnn2 = models.Model(inp, x)
rnn2.trainable = False #  [2]

inp2 = layers.Input((None, 32))
x = layers.LSTM(256, return_sequences=True)(inp2)
x = layers.Dense(1)(x)
x = rnn2(x)
rnn1 = models.Model(inp2, x)
rnn1.summary()
```

Beware, both the recently added code [2] and the old one [1](which recently edited) have `trainable = False`, it means this model **will not** being trained at all. Assume that you put `RNN2.predict` in the loss function. If you want to train it also then remove these lines.

Comment: The input to rnn2 is supposed to be a list, but y_pred is a tensor. Isn't that a problem?

Comment: So `rnn2` isn't a Keras Model?

Comment: RNN2 is a Keras model

Comment: Do Keras models accept intermediate tensors as inputs? I thought only numpy arrays were legal inputs for a Keras model

Comment: The word `input` has 2(two) meanings here. One is when you call functions like `fit` or `predict` and other is when you create a model.

Comment: A `Model` itself is a tensor, you can use it as a `Layer` just like `Conv2D` or `LSTM`.

Comment: For your question, `model(x)` needs `x` as a `Tensor`, while `model.predict(x)` needs an `ndarray`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how i can use a Model(RNN2) as a Layer in RNN1?

Comment: `model.add(RNN2, trainable=False)`
throws an error 
_add() got an unexpected keyword argument 'trainable'_

Comment: Oops, I thought you can do that. I edited the answer.

Comment: Added the answer of "Can you elaborate on how i can use a Model(RNN2) as a Layer in RNN1?"

Comment: I have tried certain work arounds, and it still leads me to the same issue. Can you tell me a way where i have two RNNs in sequence (rnn 1 and rnn2); the output of rnn 1 is input to rnn 2. Now assuming rnn 2 had been trained, how do I train rnn 1 based on its (rnn1) inputs and the output of Rnn2 (which is the rnn2 prediction of the output of rnn1)

Comment: My example sisn't work? I just move the `Dense` to be above `rnn2` per your request but the concept is same though.

Comment: What the result of my previous suggestion?

Comment: Previous suggestion causes issue because I can't do rnn2(x) , as x is a placeholder tensor whereas the inputs to rnn2 has to be an actual value ( float)

Comment: Did you use the exact same code I wrote? If so then show me the stacktrace.

Comment: Reference that it works https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1DtF-C5rbktt6nMGR1LWSwIB1b_A3juI0

Comment: Ah i see, that was elegant. Can the same thing work with the keras defined Mean absolute error as loss function? instead of custom loss?

Comment: It should, I never try it in real data though